# adding event listeners to ng-tags-input

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I want to add focus and blur events to the inputs in my form. I have Added it to my custom directives and inputs, but i am using `ng-tags-input` as well, how can i register event listeners to that? probably modifying`tagsInputConfig`, but i am not able to implement it properly .. Or should i use a different approach to add event listener to the parent form and implement event bubbling in the child elements . But i guess event capturing is supported in IE9+ , Can anyone tell me an approach which can work on IE8 as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ngTagsInput supports both `ngFocus` and `ngBlur` directives:

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" ng-focus="focus()" ng-blur="blur()"></tags-input>
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/P6DIO7O6lbosKMoNTcPw?p=preview)

That should be better documented, I must admit it. :|

Finally, ngTagsInput only works with IE10+. If you need to support older versions of that browser, perhaps you should check out [this fork](https://github.com/Bessonov/ngTagsInput.ie8).